# Write Date only to Registry vb net

Tags: .net, vb.net, registry

With this code i'm writing current time and date to registry.

What if i want only to store date ? I Tried with `Date.Now` instead of `Now` .

```
   Private Function HandleRegistry() As Boolean
    Dim firstRunDate As Date
    firstRunDate = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MyProg", "FirstRun", Nothing)
    If firstRunDate = Nothing Then
        firstRunDate = Now
        My.Computer.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MyProg", "FirstRun", firstRunDate)
    ElseIf (Now - firstRunDate).Days > 15 Then
        Return False
    End If
    Return True
End Function
```

Also if i was looking about hash in vb.net . There says id can be used Md5 is there any stronger protection because everyone first time try to unhash with md5 ? Any custom made has something like take asci value of each letter add to it number "3" and read that asci value again ? Do you understand me ?

Comment: Have you tried Date.today?

Comment: @NMK it add's the todays date + 12:00:00

Comment: You need the data in a format that can be written to the registry.  DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks is an obvious choice.  You are not looking for a hash, you need to *encrypt*.  System.Security.Cryptography namespace.  Not much point in spending heavy time on this, the user can trivially find and delete the registry keys of course.

Answer (score 1):

Now and DateTime.Now are the same thing. What you want is Today or DateTime.Today

These will give you the date and the time as-of midnight but if you don't want the time, you can format using something like this:

```
DateTime.Today.ToString("d")
```

As for the encryption, there are a lot of options out there as long as you pick something 128bit or better you will be fine. I assume you are storing the date for some type of timed trial? If so, anything you do can be circumvented easily so don't put too much effort into it.

Comment: And for a more generic way to get just the date from any datetime, use the Datetime's `.Date` property: so `Now.Date` is the same as `Today`.

Comment: WHAT didn't work? If you attempt to put it into a Date or DateTime (which are the same) it will add the time of midnight to it. What are you trying to do? Why do you only want the date? Please explain more info.